# Is a master table with only one column necessary in this mysql example?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a mysql DB with a table that holds version information for multiple other tables. In order to link to the same family of versions I have a version_master table that holds a primary key to the family of versions that the link refers to. I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution without the need for a version_master table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `version` (
`version_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`version_master_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`major` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`minor` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`patch` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`version_id`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `version_master` (
`version_master_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `needs_versions` (
`needs_versions_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`version_master_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`needs_versions_id`));
```

Answer (score 2):

In this example you can certainly eliminate the `version_master` table and use the combination of `version_id` and `version_master_id` fields as an index. I think you can just drop it, because nothing seem to refer to it with a foreign key.

However, having `version_master` would be a good idea if you had additional information associated with each family of versions.

Also, you are trying to make a primary key out of the undefined column `offer_type_id`. It is not clear whether you can logically merge `needs_versions` with `version_master` or not. The name itself is not very descriptive. I would recommend not to use verbs in table names.

Comment: Thanks.
offer_type_id was a copy paste error, corrected.
The needs_versions table is only an example of several tables that all link to the versions table for version control.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with using multiple columns as an index. How would I quickly make a new version_master_id without auto incrementing the version_master table.

Comment: To answer myself, I could use a SELECT MAX(version_master_id) + 1 FROM version. As long as it is indexed it should be pretty efficient.

Comment: @SystemicPlural, this will generated duplicated ids unless it is guarantied that only one connection does this. In all common situations an FOR UPDATE clause is needed in that SELECT statement.

Comment: @nhnb Thanks. I hadn't thought of that. It complicates things considerably (in my case).

Comment: One connection, or you have to use transactions. But I don't see the problem in the initial design.

Answer (score 1):

The other common way to do this is to use SEQUENCEs.

But MySQL does not seem to support them, at least the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html) contains a section on how to simulate sequences using a one row, one column table:

> Create a table to hold the sequence
>   counter and initialize it:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE sequence (id INT NOT NULL);
> INSERT INTO sequence VALUES (0);
> ```
>
> Use the table to generate sequence
>   numbers like this:
>
> ```
> UPDATE sequence SET id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id+1);
> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
> ```

Comment: This solution would be no less cumbersome as I would have to have a separate table to count the sequence. However I suppose it would take up less space if versions became large as it would only hold one row.